# "Connection Refused" on Docker node container

Tags: docker

I am attempting to run a simple Angular 1.5 app on my Mac within the a custom image built from the official Node image [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) but I get a "Connection Refused" error when attempting to access the site running inside the container. I am able to run the Angular app locally on my Mac with no error.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM        node
COPY        . /var/www
WORKDIR     /var/www
RUN         npm install
EXPOSE      8888
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

In package.json, "npm start" is set to spin up the site on port 8888:

```
"start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8888 -c-1 ./app",
```

I built the custom image like this:

```
$docker build -t beerdb-web .
```

The image builds successfully:

```
$docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
beerdb-web          latest              cf406b4dacc7        13 minutes ago      760.6 MB
```

I then launch a container from the image like so:

```
$docker run -p 8888:8888 -d cf
```

The contaier appears to be running fine and is properly mapping the container port 8888 to the docker machine port 8888:

```
$docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
828aeb67bc73        cf                  "npm start"         2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp   condescending_almeida
```

I can inspect the container and see that it has an IP address and port 8888 exposed:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
   "Bridge": "",
   "SandboxID": "0d7180998a7c0bceb0c911069538f29297422fdf98bb859eba78e6584ce65919",
   "HairpinMode": false,
   "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
   "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
   "Ports": {
       "8888/tcp": [
           {
               "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
               "HostPort": "8888"
           }
       ]
   },
   "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/0d7180998a7c",
   "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
   "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
   "EndpointID": "99bc9f9fad5a2445687327d45fb4fe29fb8267b08f119d3912720ced48b7d074",
   "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
   "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
   "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
   "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
   "IPPrefixLen": 16,
   "IPv6Gateway": "",
   "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
   "Networks": {
       "bridge": {
           "IPAMConfig": null,
           "Links": null,
           "Aliases": null,
           "NetworkID": "41b55572b74543f33c99b3f86339ad4c81e9abaacbe0e92077f36cacae29a9c0",
           "EndpointID": "99bc9f9fad5a2445687327d45fb4fe29fb8267b08f119d3912720ced48b7d074",
           "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
           "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
           "IPPrefixLen": 16,
           "IPv6Gateway": "",
           "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
           "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
           "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
       }
   }
}
```

My machine appears fine as well:

```
$docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.12.3
```

But when I navigate to http://192.168.99.100:8888/ from my Mac I get "Connection Refused".

In the snippet below I have ssh'd into the docker machine. You'll see that I can ping the IP address of the container, but when I use curl to try and hit port 8888 I get connection refused:

```
$docker-machine ssh
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 1.12.3, build HEAD : 7fc7575 - Thu Oct 27 17:23:17 UTC 2016
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
docker@default:~$ ping 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.092 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.092 ms
^C
--- 172.17.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.092/0.092/0.092 ms
docker@default:~$ 
docker@default:~$ curl 172.17.0.2:8888
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 8888: Connection refused
docker@default:~$
```

To make sure the site is running properly within the container I launched a command prompt into the container and used curl to hit localhost:8888 and my web site's home page was returned.

I believe that the custom image with built properly from the node base image and that it is functioning as expected. I believe there is a problem with either the port mapping or with the machine itself. I have a basic install of the Docker toolkit on my Mac and have not made any changes to the Default machine that runs inside VirtualBox, yet I still cannot access the web site running inside my container.

Very frustrated, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-a localhost` switch in your `http-server` command line causes the HTTP server to bind itself to the container's loopback device (`127.0.0.1`). Since the container uses a different [network namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) than the host (your Docker machine), `127.0.0.1` in the container is not equal to `127.0.0.1` on the host.

In order to be reachable from other network interfaces, bind to all available interfaces by specifying `0.0.0.0` as the bind address (`-a 0.0.0.0`, which coincidentally is also the default value for this option, allowing you to omit it entirely):

```
"start": "http-server -p 8888 -c-1 ./app",
```

Comment: That fixed it - removed -a localhost since 0.0.0.0 is the default as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Check doc here https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/

Basically you need to enable IP forwarding on docker host machine (your virtualbox)

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody landed here being on Windows platform (Docker Desktop), setting **Local Host** field during launch of the container, **is a must**. By Default the port is exposed from container, but **not** bind locally on 0.0.0.0.

[image]

The bind can be verified in container details page:

[image]